# Input parameters to a function are not being recognized. no error message

Tags: r

With or without the quotes in is.numeric("y"), the function z always outputs the error message. The parameters are not being passed.

What is going on here?

```
> y=df[,1]
> y
 [1] 5 5 5 6 6 6 6 5 6 6 6 6 5 5 5 5
> class(y) #numeric
[1] "numeric"
> 
> z <- function(i,y){
+ i=i
+ y=y
+ flag=0
+ if(is.numeric("y")=="TRUE"){   
+ mean(y)/100
+ flag=1
+ flag}
+ if(is.integer("y")=="TRUE"){
+ mean(y)/100
+ flag=1
+ flag}
+ if(flag==0){
+ cat("output error message\n")}
+ }
> 
> z(1,y)
```

output error message
>

After reading the response to this question, I made changes that seem correct to me except for the as.integer test. Since y consists of integers I wanted to be sure the function would not reject it. Do I need to replace as.integer code with anything else other than as.numeric or just remove it altogether?

I appreciated the comments. I am still learning.

Function:

```
z <- function(i, y) {
  flag = 0
  if(is.numeric(y)) {   
  result=mean(y) / 100
  flag = 1
  }
  if(is.integer(y)) {
  result=mean(y) / 100
  flag = 1
  }
  if(flag==0) {
  result=cat("i=",i,", error message: NULL non-numeric variable(s)\n");
  }
return(result)
}
```

Examples:

Input:

```
y=c(5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 5, 5, 5, 5)
z(1,y)
```

Output:

```
[1] 0.055
```

Input:

```
y=c(5, 5, "ch", 6, 6, 6, 6, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 5, 5, 5, 5)
z(1,y)
```

Output:

```
i= 1 , error message: NULL non-numeric variable(s)
NULL
```

Input:

```
m=.5*2
y=c(5, 5, m, 6, 6, 6, 6, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 5, 5, 5, 5)
z(1,y)
```

Output: With and without as.integer code

```
m=.5*2
y=c(5, 5, m, 6, 6, 6, 6, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 5, 5, 5, 5)
z(1,y)
[1] 0.0525
```

Comment: [SO] is banning you from asking questions there.  That does not mean you may ask off-topic questions here on CV! (-1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a reproducible answer it is harder to tell exactly what is going on, specifically we do not know anything about what `fsalesP` is.

Here are some things that may help.

The variables `y` created in your first line is created in the global environment and has no impact or influence on what happens inside the local environment of the function.  You could delete the first couple of lines and it would make no difference.

The first 2 lines inside the function (`i=i` and `y=y`) do not accomplish much.  what they may accomplish is to force the evaluation of promises of the parameters passed into the function.  But using `i` and/or `y` later on does this as well and you don't do anything between that would need the promises evaluated early (and using the `force` function may be the better option if you need to force argument evaluation, but most of the time you don't need to).  What those first 2 lines do not do is to get copies of the variable(s) from the global environment.  The function definition creates a local environment that will have `i` and `y` variables local to that environment that will be based on the arguments passed to the function when it is called.  Inside the function any reference to `y` (or `i`) will only see the local variable, the global variable of the same name is masked and will not be used in your function.

The code `is.numeric("y")` will always return `FALSE` since you are asking if the literal string `"Y"` is numeric, this does not access the value of the local variable named `y`.

If you change the code to `is.numeric(y)` then the result will depend on what value is passed to the function as the `y` argument.  In this case that will be whatever `fsalesP` happens to be.  If it is a numeric vector, then you should get `TRUE`, but if it is something else (including a data frame) then it will be `FALSE`.  Without knowing what is in `fsalesP` we cannot predict or explain what is happening (other than the results imply that it is something other than a numeric vector).

The lines of your code like `mean(y)/100` and `flag` have no effect (other than wasting a very small amount of time and electricity) because you do not do anything with the results.

The `is.integer` call is probably not checking what you think it is checking.  There is a mathematical concept of "integer" and there is a computer science concept of "integer", which while related are also different.  The `is.integer` function uses the CS concept and will return a value based on how the number is stored, not if it has a fractional piece or not.  Run `is.integer(0.5*2)` at the command line and you will see `FALSE` because even though `1` is a mathematical integer, it is stored as a double precision floating point number in this example.

If you want to return the `mean(y)/100` or the value of `flag` then you need an explicit `return` or have the value you want as the last line of the function.  As it is, your function will always return `NULL` since that is what `cat` returns and also the value for a `FALSE` `if` without an `else` clause.

Comment: Please see post. I made more than one change. May I just remove the as.integer part of the code? I am not sure what to replace it with. MM

Comment: @MaryA.Marion, integer is a subset of numeric, so if `is.integer` is `TRUE` then `is.numeric` will also be `TRUE` so you don't need to test for integer status.  Otherwise your new code appears to be working (but is still apparently off topic for this list).